# WPF Frame control , how to use it with usercontrols?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

I need to build some kind of phone emulator to test our webservice and have a general idea how the flow will go.
Doesn't needs to be anything fancy.
Now I made a WPF form with a phone image in it. In the display of the phone I have placed a frame. That looks good so far :)

But what now? How can I fill the frame with say the startscreen? Do I need to create a usercontrol for each page I want to view or show? Or is there another approach?
And how about databinding? I want to use MVVM, so I need to create a viewmodel for each usercontrol like we do normally? Or a viewmodel for each page?

I just discovered the WPF Frame Control and it seems there's not so much info on the net to find, or not what I want.

Thx for any pointers in the right direction.

Here is an image how it now looks:

[image: phoneEmulator]

Comment: This is completely unclear. What exactly do you want to show inside the frame? you mention a "Webservice", is that a Web Application? Please clarify

Comment: @HighCore Well I'm here to ask what the best way is. I need to test our webservice for our iPhone app. The iPhone app itself will not be build by us, but I need to build a small wpf test tool to test our webservice. The webservice just provides me with some methods to get data. And my questions is, do I need to use usercontrols or xaml pages to do this in the WPF frame. And with or without viewmodels? I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

For each view (screen) that the end user is going to see you will need to make a page that will hold all your logic and functions per page. All you do in Cycle through the pages in your own way.

```
FrameName.Navigate(PageName);
```

Remember to initialize the pages before you can use them. You can intialize them when you use the Navigate function like:

```
FrameName.Navigate(new PageName());
```

This works well for smaller projets, bigger projects you might want to use some clever way of initializing the pages because you navigate, like:

```
if(TimeToLoadPage == True)
{
    PageName pagename = new PageName();
    RunPageNavigation()
}

public Void RunPageNavigation()
{
    FrameName.Navigate(pagename);
}
```

You can data bind the width and height of the page by inheriting from the Frame (Going through Ancestry route). You can do all the content based stuff in a page exactly the same as a window. You can't however control the page like a window.

Hope this helps a bit more.